# Styles not working in production angular material with module federation

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I have a project with angular material and module federation, I'm using a mat form field in my host/shell, where locally works fine but in another environment, the mat form loses the styles.

Code webpack config:

```
shared: share({
            "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
            "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
            "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
            "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
            "@angular/flex-layout": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true },
            "@angular/material": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '>=11.0.0' },
            "@angular/animations": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true },
            rxjs: { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true, },
            ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })
```

And I added the styles in angular.json but it still does not work.

> "styles": [
> "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
> "project/src/styles.scss"
> ],

```
local: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6NGe.png
prod:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzPKw.png
```

Comment: Did you find any solution as I have also facing same issue.

Comment: Yes, I had a problem with the content-security-policy header HTTP. I added 'unsafe-inline' in the policy-directive "script-src" like this: script-src 'self''unsafe-eval''unsafe-inline'. You can view the browser console to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the style in the main component style of the module.

In my application i have the HomeComponent and in the home.component.scss i import primeNG in this way.

```
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "../../assets//custom-theme-primeng.css";
```

That's because with webpack, maybe you are sharing only a specific module and not the main module that use styles.scss and other assets